# Continuously try to bring eth0/wlan0 up

Tags: networking

Has anyone a working solution to bring up eth0/wlan0 when they are down using the information in interfaces.d/wlan0 and interfaces.d/eth0?

I would need it for an IoT device that might have an available ifconfig for eth0 or for both and ifconfig eth0 and wlan0.

I would also like the device to connect if the cabled/wifi is available some time after the device was powered.

I would need my device to reconnect whenever:

- the connection of the router drops temporarily
- the ethernet cable gets unplugged/replugged

Comment: Do you really need **ifupdown** to manage networking? It isn't default on latest Raspbian. On Raspbian Stretch there is **dhcpcd** used by default and both interfaces **wlan0** and **eth0** reconnect out of the box.

Comment: I know that. My colleague removed it because it says the ifupdown was better. is dhcpcd actually better?

Comment: I know very little about it so I need to trust who knows better.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need **ifupdown** you can use the official supported [Raspbian Stretch](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) distribution. Just flash it to a SD Card, configure **wpa_supplicant** for wifi and everything works out of the box. If you plug in an ethernet cable the RasPi will get connected. It will also do it again if plug it out and in.

The same with WiFi. Once configured the RasPi connects to the hotspot. If the hotspot gets down or the RasPi leaves its range the connection will drop of course. But it comes again when going back into the range or when the hotspot gets up.

By default **dhcpcd** is working as network system. The Raspberry Pi Foundation means it is better than **ifupdown**. I mean **systemd-networkd** is better and it seems that *ifupdown* becomes deprecated. My suggestion is to use either default *dhcpcd* or for more sophisticated use cases *systemd-networkd*.

Comment: ifupdown2 is actually quite nice and pretty popular in ISP infrastructure and datacenters.

Comment: @mniess Anyway, it's not available on the Raspbian repository.

Answer (score 1):

If using raspberry pi 3+ be aware that the driver has a bug explained here may give issues to correctly manage eth0 and wlan0: https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/1100